# Plotting columns of a dataframe with `ggplot2` return an empty graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataframe `prop_data`:

```
structure(list(Month = structure(1:10, levels = c("January", 
"February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", 
"September", "October", "November", "December"), class = "factor"), 
    `Count false` = c(3211L, 2293L, 2051L, 1689L, 1203L, 580L, 
    638L, 394L, 227L, 108L), False = c(0.946918313181952, 0.965880370682393, 
    0.948220064724919, 0.964041095890411, 0.961630695443645, 
    0.952380952380952, 0.987616099071207, 0.985, 0.934156378600823, 
    0.931034482758621), `Count true` = c(180L, 81L, 112L, 63L, 
    48L, 29L, 8L, 6L, 16L, 8L), True = c(0.0530816868180478, 
    0.0341196293176074, 0.0517799352750809, 0.035958904109589, 
    0.0383693045563549, 0.0476190476190476, 0.0123839009287926, 
    0.015, 0.065843621399177, 0.0689655172413793)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

I would like to plot the variables `False` and `True` in the same figure with different colors and labels. I would like to use `ggplot2`. Anyway, the following code

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(prop_data, aes(x = Month)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = `False`, color = "False"), size = 1.2) +
  geom_line(aes(y = `True`, color = "True"), size = 1.2) +
  labs(title = "Trend", x = "Month", y = "Proportions") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("False" = "blue", "True" = "red")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

does not work (the graph is empty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to use `group=1` in order to plot the lines:

```
ggplot(prop_data, aes(x = Month, group=1)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = `False`, color = "False"), size = 1.2) +
  geom_line(aes(y = `True`, color = "True"), size = 1.2) +
  labs(title = "Trend", x = "Month", y = "Proportions") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("False" = "blue", "True" = "red")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the answer by TarJae, I would also recommend using `pivot_longer` before plotting your data:

```r
prop_data |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = c("True", "False")) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = Month)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = value, color = name, group = name), size = 1.2) +
  labs(title = "Trend", x = "Month", y = "Proportions") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("False" = "blue", "True" = "red")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: line chart]

This saves duplicate calls to `geom_line()`, and means that you don't have to manually type out the colour values - they're picked up based on the values in the data.